# What is the best way to implement offline data storage and sync to server in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to implement offline data storage and sync data to server capability in myApplication.

I have tried to search google, and I have got options but all is related to cloud database like Firebase, Kinley.
but I want to add an offline capability to my app. and sync that data to our own server using API. How can I implement this in the best way? For now, I know about core data and Alamofire.

I am thinking about using these two implements offline and sync capability to my application.

- Want to do following operation

  1. I am going to store text data and images
  2. background sync
  3. want to store data for week or month.
     whenever got network connection want to sync automatically.

Please suggest better way!!!!

Comment: What are your requirements? What kind of data you store? How large? How frequent do you sync? Is the sync process work in background? There are a lot of missing pieces.

Comment: @Raptor, I have updated my question

Comment: I'm not able to say that it'ts the BEST option, but from your question it sounds like maybe you are discounting cloud databases with the assumption that they cannot support offline storage. I have had success using Firebase to support offline data storage. Look into the documentation - specifically persistanceEnabled and syncing firebase references. I've found that it worked really well in my situation. Image sync I had to handle outside of firebase's api, but it was just a matter of saving urls to firebase and uploading images saved locally when network was reachable.

Comment: @nwales, but I think firebase is useful when we are using firebase API or their cloud storage, right?

Comment: Since I have only used Firebase for offline storage and not the other suggestions provided, I am not in a position to say that it is the BEST option, only that it is a viable one. Don't take that comment as a recommendation against Firebase.. just qualifying my opinion since your question is asking for the BEST option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is Apple CoreData. Especially if you do not need to work with data base in multiple threads. There are also a lot of CoreData "wrappers" that simplifies work with it.

For the images, the best will be to save the images urls in core data, and the actual images in cache in some third party cache framework i.e: SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

use MagicalRecord lib. for core data. its easy to implement.